# git push and fetch via ssh bouncing

Tags: git, ssh

I have a work machine that I can access by sshing twice, once to a publicly visible ip address on my company's network, and then from there sshing to my local machine on the private network.

What is the easiest way to do git push and fetch to and from my desktop when I'm off the network?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to set up an ssh tunnel. In one window on your local machine:

```
ssh -L 2222:internal_work_address:22 public_gateway
```

This sets up a listener on localhost port 2222 that connects to internal_work_address port 22. Then, you can modify your Git remote to connect to localhost:22.

Alternately, you can use [sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle) to set this up almost transparently.

Comment: If you go the tunneling route you can also add a section to your .ssh/config like `Host workmachine|HostKeyAlias workmachine|HostName localhost|User workusername|Port 2222` (where each of those `|`s is a newline+tab). Then you can just refer to your work machine by its name once the tunnel is set up, rather than using localhost:2222.

Comment: Can you give some more details? For example, suppose I have two machines "mylaptop" and "mydesktop", where mydesktop is on the work network, and mylaptop is on my home network. Further, suppose that I can ssh to "foo.com" to get onto my work network, from where I can ssh to "1.2.3.4" to get to mydesktop. What is the sequence of steps to follow and on which machines?

Comment: OK, figured it out: the steps were `ssh -f -N -L 2222:1.2.3.4:22 foo.com` to forward laptop port 2222 through foo.com to port 22 on 1.2.3.4. Then, `git fetch ssh://localhost:2222/path/to/repo +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/mydesktop/*`, or add the corresponding remote to `.git/config`.